# Remove duplicate elements from a list of sequences ONLY if first two sequence elements are duplicated (python)

Tags: list, python-2.7, list-comprehension, element

I'd like to figure out how to remove "partial" duplicates, so to speak, in a list of sequences. In particular, if the first two elements of two (or more) sequences in the list are the same, I'd like to keep only one of those sequences in the list. I'm coding in python 2.7.

e.g., if I have:

```
    [(1, 2, 'keep'), (3, 4, 'also keep'), (1, 2, 'remove'), (3, 4, 'also remove')]
```

I would want to return

```
    [(1, 2, 'keep'), (3, 4, 'also keep')]
```

Comment: In which language you are trying to achieve this?

Comment: @BijuParvathy oooooops... just edited. Python 2.7, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two very similar functions that do what you want:

```
def partial_duplicates1(l):
    check_list = []
    final_list = []
    for item in l:
        first_two_elems = item[:2]
        if first_two_elems not in check_list:
            final_list.append(item)
            check_list.append(first_two_elems)
    return final_list


def partial_duplicates2(l):
    already_included = {item[:2]: False for item in l}
    final_list = []
    for item in l:
        first_two_elems = item[:2]
        if not already_included[first_two_elems]:
            final_list.append(item)
            already_included[first_two_elems] = True
    return final_list
```